# why are the widgets not displayed

Tags: html, widget, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I have a simple web page that contain a widget

http://www.mccdepot.com.au/index6.html

This works on chrome, IE, firefox and safari.

But on a samsung TV I have the inbuilt browser does not show anything at all.

The browser is launched with an application called 'URL Launcher'

The model number is DM40E and it is using a browser called 'Hospitality browser' but the underlying browser is tizen.

When i checked the browser using whatbrowser.org it told me it was 'webkit nightly 537'

Can anyone help? any way to get these widegts shown on my tv.. I have no control of the widget code..

Any help is apprceiated

TV Model - http://displaysolutions.samsung.com/digital-signage/detail/431/DM40E
Ta

Vik

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to access the iFrame source URL (https://cdnres.willyweather.com.au/widget/loadView.html?id=43747) directly?

If that works, it probably has something to do with the TV browser not supporting or purposely preventing iFrame content.

Comment: the TV comes up and says network could not be found... but as soon as I change the URL to something like www.google.com it renders the page...

Comment: so why does it have issues with the URL?

Comment: Your TV might have some network connectivity issues. It could be displaying a cached version of www.google.com, even if you aren't successfully connected to the Internet.